# Are Russian cities other than Moscow and Petersburg expensive?

Tags: hotels, russia

How about cities like Kazan, Ekaterinburg, Novosibirsk, or Irkutsk?
I am especially concerned with the hotel price. Is it possible to get a decent hotel close to the train station for 30 euro a night in November or December?

Comment: You should define decent.

Comment: like a single room? I do not need much fancy stuff.

Comment: Like amenities in the room or don't care, like a modern hotel or will the old Soviet style suffice.

Comment: Anyway, i just need a place to sleep. It does not need to be fancy.

Comment: You're talking about 11 time zones!  Close voting as too broad

Comment: Because of political situation `EURO` is `70 RUR`, so `30 EURO` equal to `2100 RUR` which is very good price for a hotel. You can find a hotel for such price even in Moscow with `airbnb` or `booking.com`. So you no need to worry. One advice - book it as soon as possible. Winter time isn't very friendly for foreigners who trying to find a place to sleep at night.

Comment: Just look prices up on Booking.com, Hotels.com or AirBnB. AirBnB in big cities apart from the capitals is full of offers of entire apartments for $15..30 per night, supplied by specialized agencies.